# DRY version of a list

Tags: python

What would be the most efficient way to do the following:

```
genres = [value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (1)', n),
          value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (2)', n),
          value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (3)', n),
          value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (4)', n),]
```

I tried doing it with a list comprehension -- `genres = [value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (%s)'%(i), n) for i in range[1,4]]`, but it kept raising a TypeError saying object is unsubscriptable. What would be the DRY way of doing the above? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the square brackets `[1,4]` with round braces `(1,4)` in your call to `range`:

```
genres = [value_from_key(wb, 'Genre (%s)'%(i), n) for i in range(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

> but it kept raising a TypeError saying object is unsubscriptable.

Because `range[1,4]` means "use the tuple `(1, 4)` as a subscript for `range`". Since `range` is a function, you want to call it, i.e. put the arguments in parentheses (just as you do for `value_from_key`). I don't really see how you would conclude from an error like this that there's something wrong with the list comprehension itself. o_O

> What would be the DRY way of doing the above?

With the list comprehension.